# Never use Turbolinks to load a specific route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

I know that I can use the `data-no-turbolink` attribute to ensure that a link (or many links) don't use turbolinks, but is there any way to ensure that *a specific page will never be loaded via turbolinks*?

I have a particular page that is broken when loaded via turbolinks, and instead of employing some hacks to fix this, I'd rather that this page just always load in the usual fashion.

I know I can add `data-no-turbolink` to all links going to this page, but then I'd have to remember to do this to every subsequent link to this page, which is pretty hacky.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To modify all new and existing URLs to remove turbolinks to a specific URL, read below:

Since you're wanting to always use "data-no-turbolinks" when linking to a specific page via `link_to`, you can modify the method to check the URL of its destination and set the `data-no-turbolinks` attribute.

Modify the `link_to` helper (be sure to replace `ROUTE_url` and `ROUTE_path` with the correct variables from your routes:

```
# application_helper.rb
def link_to(name, path, options = {})
  no_turbolink_routes = [ROUTE_url, ROUTE_path]  # Add URLs/PATHs here

  if no_turbolink_routes.include? path
    options['data-no-turbolinks'] = 'true'
  end

  super(name, path, options)
end
```

Comment: Yes, I've since arrived at this same solution, so I'll mark this as correct. Once note I'll make is that since `link_to` has a few "signatures", my code will probably be a bit brittle, and tied to the implementation of `link_to`. On the other hand, I don't expect the Rails team to break backwards compatibility of this crucial method anytime soon, so perhaps I'm safe. Either way, the solution is a bit of a hack, and I wish that turbolinks offered a better way...

Comment: Ideally you would create a custom link_to method (`my_link_to`), however, since you already mentioned that you do not want to go through all your files and edit them, overriding your `link_to` method is the best option.

Answer (score -1):

You can add the following code to your application's helper file. It will check the controller and action being called on the page, then return an HTML attribute if it matches.

```
# application_helper.rb
def no_turbolinks
  "data-no-turbolinks='true'".html_safe if controller_name == "your_controller" && action_name == "your_action"
end
```

Then, in your application's HTML:

```
<body <%= no_turbolinks %>>
```

Ideally, this would only load on the specific page that you want it to; disabling turbolinks for that one page.

Comment: No, I don't believe this does what I want. This would make all links _on_ that page not use turbolinks, whereas I want all links _to_ that page to not use turbolinks.

Comment: Aha, interesting little difference there. I understand what you mean now. I'll update my answer to reflect